# NestJS/graphql intercepting graphql response

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, middleware

What's the best way to intercept a response before sending it back in nestjs/graphql?

I'm trying to intercept a response of a query result, extracting some of the data into the context.extensions before sending it back.
I've tried applying a middleware using graphql-middleware but it does not work.

this is what i've tried doing

```
export const Pagination: MiddlewareFn = async ({ info }, next) => {
// here i'm trying to extract the data
};
```

and this is where i'm trying to put it (resolver.ts)

```
@UseMiddleware(Pagination)
  findAll(options: PaginationInput): Promise<PaginatedReport> {
    return applyPagination(this.reportRepository, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not [use an interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) which was made specifically for intercepting responses before business logic and post business logic? There are several great examples on the docs site (linked above).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing interceptors, you can play within the Execution context too, here's full documentation about that [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors), if you need more Execution context you can visit [Execution context](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context)